# Вопрос о синтаксисе закрывающих тегов php

Tags: php

Просто из любопытства решил задать этот вопрос. В некоторых очень известных CMS принято не закрывать тег `<?php`

Примерно выглядит так.

```
<?php

// код
```

Как-то давно читал, что это связано с безопасностью приложения, и что, якобы, если там что-то кто-то забудет то последствия ужасны. Но меня, честно говоря, такой подход несколько раздражает. Потому, что открыть и закрыть это первое что я делаю прежде чем углубиться в раздумья. Если кто-то может обосновано разъяснить зачем реально нужен этот изврат, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Для примера, в [стандарте Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/ru/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html#coding-standard.php-file-formatting.general) это объясняется сл.:

> Для файлов, содержащих только PHP-код, закрывающий тег ("?>") не разрешен. Он не требуется синтаксисом PHP и его пропуск предотвращает случайное включение в вывод конечных пробелов.

На мой взгляд это хорошая практика, проще не ставить закрывающий тег вовсе, чем следить, что бы после него не затерялся пробельный символ.

Answer (score 1):

Самая большая проблема это, наверное, лишний пробел после ?>
Т.к. потом уже не сможешь, например, воспользоватся `header`...
Вообще, откровенно говоря - ничего такого страшного в закрытии нет...
Кстати а в чем изврат? Если вы пишите ООП код то вам вообще всеравно закрывать или нет :)
Если же нет, тогда да, тогда не заморачивайтесь и закрывайте себе наздоровье ;)

Comment: Считаю извратом все что уходит за рамки спецификации создания документа этого вида. Если тег открыт значит он должен быть закрыт. Ну вот такая у меня мания короче.

Comment: Рассматривайте "тег" как указание веб серверу на блок php кода, может так станет проще :)

Answer (score 1):

Всегда закрываю, всегда вычищаю пробелы после и до(точнее, за меня это делает IDE). 
Не закрывать считаю извратом, так как это рвет шаблон моего XMLного восприятия документа.

Comment: Точно такие же ощущения :)

Comment: > так как это рвет шаблон моего XMLного восприятия документа

В тегах `<?php` и `?>` от XML'я только слово "тег".

Comment: но это не мешает их воспринимать как единое целое

Answer (score 0):

Например, во избежание parse error. Я сам никогда не закрываю